# Libgdx infinite horizontal scroll with actor class

Tags: java, scroll

I have a class called "Spaceship" that extends Actor class. It is added to a group class. The group class is added to stage.

I want my spaceship to reappear at the left side of the screen when it disappears on the right side, including when only a portion of the spaceship has disappeared.

[image]

Here is the spaceship class:

```
class Spaceship extends Actor() {
    Sprite sprite;
    
    public Spaceship(Texture texture) {
        sprite = new Sprite(texture);
        sprite.setPosition(getX(), getY());
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        sprite.setPosition(getX(), getY());
    }
}
```

Here is the Group class:

```
class SpaceshipLayer extends Group {
    Spaceship spaceship;
    ...
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        if (isRightKeyPressed) {
            spaceship.moveBy(5, 0);
            if (spaceship.getX() > screenWidth) {
                // No working properly
                spaceship.setX(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my main screen class:

```
class Main implements Screen {
    SpaceshipLayer spaceshipLayer;
    Stage stage;
    
    public Main() {
        stage = new Stage();
        spaceshipLayer = new SpaceshipLayer();
        stage.addActor(spaceshipLayer );
    }
   
    ...
}
```

I am using actor coordinates for collision, etc. It is possible to do the horizontal scroll keeping sprite and actor values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if it is the best solution, but this is how I did it. I created an array of two spaceships with a distance difference between these two. So, when one of them disappeared to the right, the another one appears from the left.

```
class SpaceshipLayer extends Group {
    Spaceship[] spaceships = new Spaceship[2];
    
    public SpaceshipLayer() {
        ...
        // set X at center of screen
        spaceships[0].setX(getWidth / 2);

        // spacesship location - screen width 
        spaceships[1].setX(spaceships[0].getX() - getWidth());
    }
    
    ...
    
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        if (isRightKeyPressed) {
            for (Spaceship spaceship : spaceships) {
                spaceship.moveBy(5, 0);
            }
        }

        ...

        for (Spaceship spaceship : spaceships) {
            ...
            if (spaceship.getX() > getWidth()) {
                spaceship.setX(0 - spaceship.getWidth);
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```